# X Starting Instead of Openbox (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, openbox

I recently installed Arch for the first time in VMWare Workstation 9.0.2, twice (I reinstalled to change some partition sizes). In the first installation I was able to start Openbox instead of X when running startx by copying xinitrc to my /home/user directory, and then simply adding "exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch openbox-session" to the end on both the xinitrc in my user folder as well as the one in /etc/X11/xinit. However, on the second installation, although modifying xinitrc in the same manner as the first time, X starts instead of Openbox after running startx. The end of both xinitrc files look like this:

```
twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch openbox-session
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3):

[Consolekit is long deprecated](https://www.archlinux.org/news/consolekit-replaced-by-logind/) in Arch. Remove the `ck-launch-session` string from your `.xinitrc`.

You are also trying to start two window managers, `twm` and `openbox`; so remove the `twm`, `xclock` and `xterm` lines as well.

Read the [Arch Wiki Openbox article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Openbox_as_a_stand-alone_WM) on how to run Openbox as a standalone window manager. Essentially, you only need one line in your `.xinitrc`

```
exec openbox-session
```

and everything else that you want started with your session you include in `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: Well, that worked. I have no idea why openbox worked along with twm in the previous installation. Thanks for the help.